# How to use catalog price rules to increase products prices instead of applying a discount

Tags: price, catalog, ce-1.9.2.2, price-rules

I want to change prices of products based on the category and the customer group the client belongs.

So to do so I thought using the catalog price rules and instead of set 20% to decrease the price, put 120% to increase it. But it doesn't work.

So if a product costs 100€, to the group A would cost 120€

Any ideas about how to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Magento assumes that discounts are always decreasing the price and to change this behaviour you would have to make modifications to several core files (or use proper [overrides](/questions/tagged/overrides)).

A practical solution to your situation would be to set the highest possible price (i.e. 120 €) as product price and use price rules to make it cheaper for everybody *except* those in your 120% group.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest having a *list-price* or *msrp* that represents the highest possible price as the base price in Magento.
From there apply the proper discounts to each of your customer groups or any other rules you might want to apply.
In general, adhering to the standard functionality in Magento will produce better results than tweaking it.